# ASP Login template custom drop down list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am using the standard authentication (using AD) with the `asp:login`. 
I would like to add Dropdown List to the login template (elements would be retreived from the DB).
However if I just simply add:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDomain" runat="server"/>
```

It is not accessible from the code. After the login is successful I want the value from ddlDomain to be added to the session.

Do I need to handle whole login by myself or is there a way to add the element to the template?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Login1.LoginView.FindControl("ddlDomain");
```

to get yourdrop down list in code.

Comment: `DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)Login1.FindControl("ddlDomain");` Worked for me. Thanks!